# Error: can't allocate enough memory to (parted) GRM - GCTA 64/ python

Tags: python, linux, out-of-memory, genetics

I am processing some genetic data using gcta64 via python through os.system() (in a screen). However, I am running through a memory problem.
My machine is a VM instance from google cloud with 1 TB of memory.

The first picture is a screenshot of my htop and the second is a screenshot of the code/error.
You can clearly see that I have enough memory. Also I am running another task, but I don't think this is the problem. I stopped it and ran the gcta task but I got the same error.
Thank you,

It is very appreciated

---

[image: screenshot of my htop]

---

[image: screenshot of the code/error]

Comment: Whatever you're running is asking for 1777GB, which is indeed more than 1TB. Not sure what is causing it but you are running out of memory and 1TB may not be enough

Comment: Thanks  @MitchelPaulin . Sorry I got confused with the numbers (rough day). I wanted to know if there was a way to use less memory. I cannot afford a machine with more than 1 TB

Comment: Maybe if you can chunk the data, I dont know anything about genetics but can you partition the data and do your computations on those?

Answer (score 0):

you can divide the data 
using `--make-grm-part n i`
where n is the number of folds and i is the ith fold. so for example: 
you want to divide by 3

```
--make-grm-part 3 1 ...
--make-grm-part 3 2 ...
--make-grm-part 3 3 ...
```

and you can concatenate the results.
for more info see the --make-grm-part discussion under https://cnsgenomics.com/software/gcta/#MakingaGRM .